# netbeans not showing c++ output

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, terminal, output

I've tried reading several different help forum results on google search results and none of them seem to apply to my situation. My Netbeans 8.0.2 isn't showing any output. I have programs that have cout's in functions and others with cout in the main. Nothing shows up. Kicker is that there are no returned errors. Not sure if you guys can help me but I'm remaining hopeful.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Netbean version: 8.0.2

Here is an example code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class calender
{
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
public:
    void getdate(int m, int d, int y);
    void showdate();
};

void calender::getdate(int m, int d, int y){
        m=month;
        d=day;
        y=year;
}

void calender::showdate(){
        cout<<"The date is:"<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<month<<"/"<<setw(2)<<day
                <<"/"<<setw(2)<<year<<endl;
}

int main() {
    int month, day, year;
    char contin;
    while (contin=='y'){
    calender c1;
    cout<<"What is the month:  ";
    cin>>month;
    cout<<"What is the day:  ";
    cin>>day;
    cout<<"What is the year:  ";
    cin>>year;
    c1.getdate(month,day,year);
    c1.showdate();
    cout<<"Do you want to continue(y/n): ";
    cin>>contin;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: That was dumb of me -- as written, your code will not have any output anyway. You never initialize your variable `contin`, so the conditional statement in the `while` loop never evaluates to `true`. Are you sure this is not your problem?

Comment: I showed the code so it could be ran in case there was something in the code, I just wanted to cover all the bases. Secondly, yes I know where and the window I get (both internal terminal and external terminal) the blinking text holder. Not a single thing of output from the program.